# angularJS change url notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, location

For statistics purpose,
I want to know how many time the url was change
So I decalte a counter and I want to increase the counter every time the url is change.

Anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help..
but what did the trick for me was:

```
var counter = 0;
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        counter++;
    });
});
```

I guess that is way Angular is so cool.. there some many ways to solve each problem..

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to `$routeChangeStart` event on `$rootScope` and increase counter

```
var count=0;
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {

             count = count++;

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `$routeProvider`  there are several events broadcast you can monitor.

`$routeChangeSuccess` is likely the one you want. Where you use it would depend on how your counter is set up.

You can listen for it on any scope using `scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', callback)`